# Instance method '-supportsOrientation' not found

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode4

I am creating one app using cordova 2.1.0, but during building process, I am getting the following warning

Instance method '-supportsOrientation:' not found (return type Defaults to  'id').

This is my AppDelegate.m file -

```
/*
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
 */

//
//  AppDelegate.m
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___ ___YEAR___. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window, viewController;

- (id) init
{   
    /** If you need to do any extra app-specific initialization, you can do it here
     *  -jm
     **/
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]; 
    [cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

#pragma UIApplicationDelegate implementation

/**
 * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here. (preferred - iOS4 and up)
 */
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{    
    NSURL* url = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    NSString* invokeString = nil;

    if (url && [url isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
        invokeString = [url absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"Shop launchOptions = %@", url);
    }    

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
    self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
    self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
   // self.viewController.invokeString = invokeString;

    // NOTE: To control the view's frame size, override [self.viewController viewWillAppear:] in your view controller.

    // check whether the current orientation is supported: if it is, keep it, rather than forcing a rotation
    BOOL forceStartupRotation = YES;
    UIDeviceOrientation curDevOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if (UIDeviceOrientationUnknown == curDevOrientation) {
        // UIDevice isn't firing orientation notifications yet… go look at the status bar
        curDevOrientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    }

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(curDevOrientation)) {
        if ([self.viewController supportsOrientation:curDevOrientation]) {
            forceStartupRotation = NO;
        } 
    } 

    if (forceStartupRotation) {
        UIInterfaceOrientation newOrient;
        if ([self.viewController supportsOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait])
            newOrient = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        else if ([self.viewController supportsOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft])
            newOrient = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
        else if ([self.viewController supportsOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight])
            newOrient = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
        else
            newOrient = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;

        NSLog(@"AppDelegate forcing status bar to: %d from: %d", newOrient, curDevOrientation);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:newOrient];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

// this happens while we are running ( in the background, or from within our own app )
// only valid if Shop-Info.plist specifies a protocol to handle
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url 
{
    if (!url) { 
        return NO; 
    }

    // calls into javascript global function 'handleOpenURL'
    NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"handleOpenURL(\"%@\");", url];
    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    // all plugins will get the notification, and their handlers will be called 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification object:url]];

    return YES;    
}

- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{    
    // IPhone doesn't support upside down by default, while the IPad does.  Override to allow all orientations always, and let the root view controller decide whats allowed (the supported orientations mask gets intersected).
    NSUInteger supportedInterfaceOrientations = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    return supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

@end
```

I am not able to run the app also, following error is getting displayed on the log -

```
2012-10-03 16:38:07.653 Shop[829:13403] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-10-03 16:38:07.671 Shop[829:13403] -[MainViewController supportsOrientation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e725e0
2012-10-03 16:38:07.718 Shop[829:13403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController supportsOrientation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e725e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a2022 0x207dcd6 0x1a3cbd 0x108ed0 0x108cb2 0x2dfa 0x337386 0x338274 0x347183 0x347c38 0x33b634 0x271fef5 0x176195 0xdaff2 0xd98da 0xd8d84 0xd8c9b 0x337c65 0x339626 0x290c 0x28a5 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

I was not able to find anything related to it...

Answer (score 0):

What I found worked is removing armv6 from the architecture and valid architecture list and adding armv7s

In Xcode:

- Project Navigation > Your Project > Build Settings tab
- In search box, search for Architectures
- Select: Standard armv7 armv7s
- Project Navigation  > CordovaLib.xcodeproj > Build Settings tab
- In search box, search for Architectures
- Select: Standard armv7 armv7s
- In search box search for Valid Architectures
- Remove armv6
- Add armv7s

Comment: Thanks for replying, but unfourtunately I have removed Cordova 2.1.0 and installed Cordova 2.0.0. Since it was kind of urgent. However, I am planing to install 2.1 again and will let you know if I face any problem again after following these steps.